# How to search with Bash for all files/folders that contain a given substring in their paths?

Tags: bash

I want to search for files which names include the word "able" in any folder which name contains the word "dir".

How can I do this using Bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `find` command.

`find . -iwholename '*dir*/*able*'`

> [Full Name Patterns - Finding Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Full-Name-Patterns.html)
>
> Test: **-wholename** *pattern*: 
>   True if the entire file name, starting with
>   the command line argument under which the file was found, matches
>   shell pattern pattern.
>
> Test: **-iwholename** *pattern*: ... but the match is case-insensitive.